# Let $X_{n}\sim Bin(n,p_{n})$ and suppose $np_{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} \infty$. Show that $P(X_n\geq 1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 1$.

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

This is a 2-part question.
[image]

**My answer for part (a).** Note that $E(X_n)=np_n$ and that $X_n$ is a nonnegative random variable (since it's binomial). We can use Markov's inequality which tells us $$0\leq P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{np_{n}}{\epsilon^{2}}.$$ Then we let $n \rightarrow \infty$ and use the Sandwich theorem to complete the proof.

Can someone confirm this is right? Also **for part (b)** I'm struggling to get started, but imagine I have to use Chebyshev's inequality. Is this just normal convergence rather than convergence in probability? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint for b): Show that $P(X_n=0)\to0$.

Comment: @Did Hi thanks for replying. I'm a little confused given all the probablistic convergence definitions (in probability, in distribution, almost surely). This one is just the usual convergence, right? I'm guessing I want $$0 \leq P(X_n=0) < ??$$ where the RHS is probably given by something like Markov/Chebyshev's and has $np_{n}$ on the denominator so I can use the Sandwich theorem. I'm not sure how to get to that point though.

Comment: @Did Hello, I've since read that there's a specialised form of Chebyshev’s inequality for counting random variables: $P(X=0)\leq Var(X)/E(X)^2$. This would allow me to do the problem easily but I can't find any other references for this generalised form online though? Is it possible to do this question without it?

Comment: Another hint: $P(X_n=0)=(1-p_n)^n$. Work directly with this expression; a Chebyshev-type inequality is not needed.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks Byron. Part of the question sheet (not pictured in the original post) specifically hints at using Chebyshev/Markov, so I think it would be best to just go for that on this instance but I appreciate your suggestion. Would you please be able to clarify whether my part (a) is correct, and whether the convergence referred to in (b) is just the usual one and not convergence in probability? I'm getting myself into a muddle.

Comment: Part (b) is about the convergence of the numerical sequence $P(X_n\geq1)$, it is not convergence in probability.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you :) Just finally, do you know where I can find an explanation for $P(X=0)\leq Var(X)/E(X)^2$ being true?

Comment: @Alex.F Integrate both sides of ${\bf 1}_{(X=0)}\leq \left({X\over \mu}-1\right)^2.$

Comment: @Alex.F Part (a) will be correct if you replace $\epsilon^2$ by $\epsilon$ in denominator.

Comment: @NCh Good catch, thanks!